# How to achieve www.example.com/user/johndoe instead of www.example.com?user=johndoe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I currently have this to display a user **www.example.com?user=johndoe** 
But i want this to be **www.example.com/users/1213johndoe** instead. 
What are methods to achieve this?

Comment: assuming you have apache as the webserver then a `rewrite rule` that maps `user` to a placeholder. Where does the 1213 come from?

Comment: id of the user.

Comment: does it serve any purpose?

Comment: to avoid same names

Comment: Use something like the uer's ID rather than a random name - though you could have a column in the user table for this purpose. That said, as it is currently you have that problem using `?user=fred`

Comment: i want things to be like this https://stackoverflow.com/users/3603681/ramraider instead of passing arguements

Comment: in the above `3603681` is likely to be the ID and `ramraider` the username - so the equivalent of `?id=3603681&user=ramraider`

Answer (score 1):

For Apache to accomplish the rewriting of urls as you outline you could try along these lines. In your `.htaccess` file create a rule like so

```
# turn on the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# map querystring of form?id=123&user=fred to users/123/fred
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z\s_]+)(/?)$ /?id=$1&user=$2 [NC,L]
```